# Wordpress Sidebar menu for posts based on date - guidance needed

Tags: posts, sidebar, date, calendar

One of the issues I have with WordPress is knowing when (and when it is possible) to use the WordPress back end instead of coding my own solution from scratch.  This question is based around this.

I'm attempting to set up the blog page for the site I'm working on.  Most of the site is static pages, with the posts ideally being collected on a news page.  I have the news page displaying the posts through the traditional set up (selecting the static front page, and selecting a page to be the blog page through the WordPress dashboard).  With that done, I want to create a sidebar for the blog post (and all posts) that displays a list of years and months. Example sidebar:

August 2014
July 2014
June 2014
...
October 2013

This seems like something that would be built into WordPress, but I can't seem to find any information on it.  So I ask you all, is this a built in function?  If so, could you direct me towards a good starting point?  If it is not, how would you suggest developing links to posts based off of a time stamp?

Apologies again for the low level question.  I know just enough to get my hands dirty here, but I have a ways to go on the learning curve.

Comment: Go to `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Widgets`. You are looking for `Archives` widget.

Comment: Thanks.  If you'd like, set that as the answer and I'll accept it.  To help others, I had to create a custom sidebar using `register_sidebar( $args );` and then added the archive widget to the new sidebar.  In the home.php file, I changed the `get_sidebar()` call to include the new sidebar, and made a custom sidebar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

```
Dashboard -> Appearance -> Widgets.
```

You are looking for `Archives` widget.

If your theme has built in sidebar, you'd just select the appropriate widget in that sidebar.

To create a new sidebar in your theme, you need to use `register_sidebar()` in your theme's `functions.php`.

To include a sidebar in your file, you'd use `get_sidebar()` in your theme file. You can include the sidebars dynamically from the admin panel there.